# CORS Options request fail with reverse proxy

Tags: firefox, apache-http-server, proxy, cors

I'm using an Apache 2 Server with a Tomcat Server installed. The Tomcat server includes a Geoserver and a web client, which is able to send POST requests to the Geoserver. I want to avoid the specification of the port in the URL, so I configured a reverse proxy for the Apache 2:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName localhost
   ProxyPreserveHost On
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html
   ProxyPass /.well-known !
   ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/crowdmapping/
   ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/crowdmapping/
   Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
   Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, OPTIONS"
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type"
</VirtualHost>
```

If I access the web client by the url, which is indicated in the `ServerName` part of the reverse proxy configuration, I get a CORS error by using the Firefox browser on a PC. This also occurs by using Safari, Chrome and Firefox on mobile devices (tested with an iPhone 12 and iPad Air 4).

In Firefox network tab, a "CORS Missing Allow Origin" error occurs, which concerns the preflight request (`OPTIONS`). By using the Chrome browser or MS Edge on a PC, everything works fine.

If the web client is accessed by the url, which is configured in `ProxyPass`, everything works as it should (even with Firefox and on mobile devices).

By investigating this occurrence, I' ve detected two interesting questions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38400168/cors-access-control-allow-origin-on-apache-proxy-issue
- https://serverfault.com/questions/1078707/cors-multiple-origin-not-allowed-using-parse-server-and-apache2?newreg=9f64f588d0944f2d9f66e113f9127dff

I've tried to implement the answered suggestions, but the error still appears.

Does anybody know how to fix it?